# How to get innerscroll working on fancybox in Android Gingerbread version

Tags: javascript, android

I am trying to use the Fancybox JScript downloaded from Fancybox.net. When i execute the fancy box though there is enough text, am not able to see the scroll bar, i can not scroll the text in Fancy box. This works well on desktop.

Please open fancybox.net on Android Phone and click on "•Inline - auto detect width / height" under the various examples. Check the same on desktop.

Please help

Best Regards
Vinod

Answer (score 0):

The inner scroll on a popup in Android GB is not supported, it needs to be implemented in the Webkit library.. So complex thing to achieve the same

Instead use the Webview as popdialog to achiev the desired result..

Thanks

Best Regards
Vinod